# How to pass data from a template to the Django side

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I just started to code Python Django. I just wanted to make a basic login project. I tried to pass login variables from the HTML side to file *views.py*.

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<form action="/index" method="post">

    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="username" type="email"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
        <label for="password">Password</label><a class="fs--1">Forgot Password?</a>
      </div>
      <input class="form-control" id="password" type="password" />
    </div>

    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" id="card-checkbox" checked="checked"/>
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="card-checkbox">Remember me</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-3"
              type="submit"
              id= "login"
              name="submit">Log in</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

My *urls.py* file:

```python
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.loginPage, name="login"),
    path('index', views.home, name="index")
]
```

My *forms.py* file:

```python
from django import forms

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.EmailField(label="Username"),
    password = forms.CharField(label="Password")
```

And my *views.py* file:

```python
def home(request):
    context =  {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        print('form:', form)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('niceee')
        else:
            return render(request, 'index.html', context)
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
```

I just want to see username and password values into *views.py*. However, I can't see variables into *views.py*. How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't think you fully understand how the django workflow works... you'll most likely want a model that is related to the form, so you can then use that model in the database.

Comment: You should pass the form you created as a context variable in if you catch a GET request in your home function and  display it in your form like this for example : <form ... > {{form.as_p}}</form>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```python
def home(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        print('form:', form)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('username:', form.cleaned_data.get('username'))
            print('password:', form.cleaned_data.get('password'))
            print('niceee')

    else:
        form = LoginForm()

    context =  {}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Check the server for username and password values.

Answer (score 0):

You are a halfway there! Once the form has been validated by Django, you can access the form's variables in its `cleaned_data` attribute:

```
def home(request):
    context =  {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        print('form:', form)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('You submitted this username:', form.cleaned_data['username'])
            print('You submitted this password:', form.cleaned_data['password'])
        else:
            return render(request, 'index.html', context)
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
```

However, consider reusing [`django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView) because then you won't have to write any Python code at all. Just customize the `registration/login.html` template.

Comment: He did not pass the form (of forms.py) in his template, so I think he should do that to be able get the data no ?

Comment: You don't _have_ to pass the form to your template, as long as you render the correct `<input>` fields yourself.

Comment: Yes, I see, but it might be easier to use your forms especially to facilitate your data with the cool form.is_valid() method. On the other hand I think it's easier to style your own forms than Django forms (By the way I'm also some kind of beginner people in Django)